# .html() returns undefined

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to JQuery and am having trouble getting the content of a div block.

```
  <div class="update_status">
    Updated successfully
  </div>
```

And when the following script runs:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(function () {
    var $status_div = $("#update_status");
    if ($status_div) {
      alert("1");
      alert($status_div.html());    
      alert("2");
    } else {
      alert("undefined");
    }
  });
});
```

I receive three alerts, "1", "undefined", and "2". I expected to get "Updated Successfully". Any ideas on what I did wrong?

Comment: JQuery uses ccs3 selectors http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/ Use `#` for ID´s and `.` for classes

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`#` is used to find elements by `id`.  You are using a class so you need `.`

```
$(".update_status");
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Oh my goodness, it's always something simple. I don't know why I overlooked that. Thank you! I'm going to take this as a sign I should go to bed.

Answer (score 3):

`update_status` is a class, so the selector should be the following:

`var $status_div = $(".update_status");`

Answer (score 3):

Change class to id

```
<div class="update_status">
    Updated successfully
  </div>
```

To

```
<div id="update_status">
    Updated successfully
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.` instead of `#` since it is a `class` not an `id`

`var $status_div = $(".update_status");`

**And also use**

`if ($status_div.length) {`

rather than

`if ($status_div) {`

because the latter always returns a `true`